# JPA @JoinFormula with BindParameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, joincolumn

I have a @OneToOne relationship described as below:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
        {
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        column = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
                ),
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        column = @JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_NAME", referencedColumnName = "CONFIG_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
                ),
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'PT-BT'", referencedColumnName = "LANG_ID")
                )
        }
)
private ConfigurationLanguage language;
```

The column `LANG_ID`is PrimaryKey on the table mapped by the `ConfigurationLanguage`entity.

But now, instead of using the JoinFormula value as hardcoded, I need to pass it dynamically, using a bind parameter...

Something like this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
        {
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        column = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
                ),
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        column = @JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_NAME", referencedColumnName = "CONFIG_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
                ),
                @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                        formula = @JoinFormula(value = ":languageId", referencedColumnName = "LANG_ID")
                )
        }
)
private ConfigurationLanguage language;
```

Passing it to the JPQL Query as bellow:

```
TypedQuery<ConfigurationCompany> query = manager.createQuery("select c from ConfigurationCompany c " +
        "join c.language l " +
        "where c.id.customerId = :customerId " +
        "and c.id.companyId = :companyId " +
        "and c.id.productId = :productId " +
        "and c.id.codFilial = :codFilial " +
        "and (c.id.configName in :configNames or :configNamesEmpty = true)", ConfigurationCompany.class);

query.setParameter("customerId", customerId);
query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
query.setParameter("productId", productId);
query.setParameter("codFilial", codFilial);
query.setParameter("configNames", configNames);
query.setParameter("configNamesEmpty", configNamesEmpty);
query.setParameter("languageId", "PT-BR"); //<<<< THIS PARAMETER
```

But it's not working:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Invalid filter-parameter name format [languageId]; expecting {filter-name}.{param-name}
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025795/how-to-accept-orderby-of-jpa-sort-value-as-a-dynamic-parameter/63076842#63076842

Comment: Sorry @JLazar0 but I didn't realize how your topic match my issue...

Comment: Regarding the first part, to indicate that it is not possible.

What values ​​do the strings take when you create the query?